# Why am I getting InvalidCredentials error from Marvel API?

Tags: reactjs, api, create-react-app

I am building a simple app with create-react-app and Marvel to Marvel API. The app only needs to show a list of characters. This is my first time trying to do this, so I am not very familiar with environment files.

I have a `.env` file in `/src` which hold these two keys and nothing else:

`REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY='publicKey'`
`REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY='privateKey'`

Also in `/src` I have `/config/config.js`. `config.js` is then imported into `App.js`. `config.js` looks like this:

```
const marvelURL = 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/',
      apiKey = `apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`;

const getCharacters = (options) => {
const {
    offset,
    name,
    exactMatch,
    sortName,
    limit,
} = Object.assign({
    offset: 0,
    name: '',
    exactMatch: false,
    limit: 20,
}, options);

let url = `${marvelURL}characters?${apiKey}&offset=${offset}&orderBy=${sortName}name&limit=${limit}`;

if (name) {
    if (exactMatch) {
        url += `&name=${name}`;
    } else {
        url += `&nameStartsWith=${name}`;
    }
}

return fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((resObj) => {
    try {
        if (resObj.code === 200) {
            if (offset > resObj.data.total) {
                throw new Error('This page does not exist.');
            } else {
                const pages = Math.floor(resObj.data.total / limit);
                return {
                    characters: resObj.data.results,
                    maxPage: resObj.data.total % limit > 0 ? pages + 1 : pages,
                };
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Bad response from API. Status code ${resObj.code}.`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return {
            characters: [],
            maxPage: 0,
        };
    }
});
}

export { getCharacters };
```

Comment: What happens if you try to hit the URL in browser??

Comment: @pritesh, an error in the console which says that I'm unauthorized. My api key shows up as undefined. So it seems there's a disconnect between config.js and .env but I don't know how to connect them.

Comment: Might be typo in config.js you are importing `apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_API_KEY}` but in environment file your API key name is `REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY`

Comment: Change to this in config.js `apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY}`

Comment: Did that. `apiKey` is still returning undefined...